# Refer to OpenArgs to identify field name

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am having some issues trying to use OpenArgs to refer to a field name in a table. I'm fairly new to this so please bear with me.

So I have a Report(CourseCatalog) that has text boxes with course names that it pulls from a table(tblCourses). When you click on a course, it opens a Form which gives you the option to rate the course(frmRate). I use OpenArgs (from the report to the rating form) to make the caption for frmRate. Works fine.

Now i need to take the data (number of stars selected, (intNumStars)), which is defined previously in the code, and put it into a table. That table ("Allratings") has course names (the OpenArgs value) as the column names and I want to put the intNumStars(1-5) into the cells in those columns.

I seem to have some problems referring to the VarArgs to accomplish that. My syntax/logic may be (is probably) wrong, and if anyone knows a better way to accomplish this task, please let me know what you think! Thank you!

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Dim varargs
Dim rst As dao.Recordset
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim fld As dao.Field
varargs = Me.OpenArgs
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Allratings")

For Each fld In rst.Fields
    If fld.Name = "varargs" Then
        rst.AddNew
        rst!"varargs" = intNumStars
        rst.Update
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: *That table ("Allratings") has course names as the field names* - if this is true (and you don't mean you have a column for course name), this is bad design. This should be a junction table (see Wikipedia).

Comment: I misspoke there, it's the column names vice the field names. I edited the post to reflect the correction

Answer (score 1):

You're doing weird things with strings, and you should get a descriptive compile error when you try to save/compile this.

`varargs` refers to the variable `varargs`

`"varargs"` is a literal string containing the letters v, a, r, etc.

`rst!"varargs"` should be `rst.Fields("varargs")` to avoid a compile error, but should actually be `rst.Fields(varargs)`

If you correct all incorrectly placed quotes, you get:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Dim varargs As String
Dim rst As dao.Recordset
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim fld As dao.Field
varargs = Me.OpenArgs
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Allratings")

For Each fld In rst.Fields
    If fld.Name = varargs Then
        rst.AddNew
        rst.Fields(varargs) = intNumStars
        rst.Update
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

This seems valid, if `Me.OpenArgs` contains only a field name

Comment: I assumed I was making some errors like that. I don't know when to use quotation marks when referring to an object and when not to. However, after making the corrections you suggested, I'm having the same issue I was before. I'm not getting an error, but nothing is happening. The table where the data is being saved isn't saving the rating

Comment: Well, that's probably because `Me.OpenArgs` is never equal to `fld.Name`, then. That's an issue elsewhere in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Eric has shown how to make your code work, but your table design will prove impractical. Adding a new column for each new course is not how you work with databases.

I suggest

**tblCourses**

```
+----------+------------+
| CourseID | CourseName |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | foo        |
|        2 | bar        |
+----------+------------+
```

**tblUsers**

```
+--------+----------+
| UserID | UserName |
+--------+----------+
|      7 | John     |
|      8 | Kate     |
+--------+----------+
```

**allRatings** (this is a [Junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity))

```
+----------+--------+----------+
| CourseID | UserID | NumStars |
+----------+--------+----------+
|        1 |      7 |        1 |
|        1 |      8 |        4 |
|        2 |      7 |        3 |
+----------+--------+----------+
```

So a new rating is a new record in `allRatings`, with fixed column names. You can get the `CourseID` from the passed Course Name with a `DLookup` call.

And a view with Courses and their ratings as columns is achieved with a **Crosstab query**.

Comment: Essentially, I was tasked to design a database that would rate our courses and create a catalog that showed the average rating of all the reviews using stars. So the reason I had the table set up that way was to make finding the DAvg using the field name with no criteria a little easier. I don’t know very much VBA. Is it possible to use the Junction table to find the average of all ratings ever submitted?

Comment: Yes, this would be trivial with an aggregate (GROUP BY) query.